# passing a variable filename to topojson

Tags: javascript, d3.js

in the following function is I do this it works:

```
    var land = topojson.feature(europe, europe.objects.nuts1);
```

but if I do this it breaks:

```
var europe_path = "europe.objects.nuts1";

var land = topojson.feature(europe, europe_path);
```

with this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

how to pass a variable to topojson?

---

The code looks like this:

```
.border {
  stroke: #000;
  fill: none;

}
.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 84px;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Administrative Sub-Regions of Europe</h1>

<select id="json_sources" name="json_sources">
    <option value ="nuts1" selected>Source 1</option>
    <option value ="nuts2">Source 2</option>
<!--     <option value ="source3.json">Source 3</option> -->
</select>​


<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/colorbrewer.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rveciana/d3-composite-projections/v0.2.0/composite-projections.min.js"></script>
<script>

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

var width = 600,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.conicConformalEurope();
var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);


// Find new colours here: http://colorbrewer2.org/
var scale =  d3.scale.quantize().domain([10,60]).range(colorbrewer.PuRd[3]);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


    svg.append("path")
        .datum(graticule)
        .attr("class", "graticule")
        .attr("d", path);



var dropdown = d3.select("#json_sources")
var change = function() {
  var source = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;


var str1 = source;
var str2 = ".json";
var file = str1.concat(str2);
console.log(file);

var str_a = "europe.objects.";
var str_b = source;
var europe_path = str_a.concat(str_b);
console.log(europe_path);


  d3.json(file, function(error, europe) {

  d3.csv("povertry_rate.csv", function(error, povrate) {

    var europe_path = "europe.objects.nuts1";

    var land = topojson.feature(europe, europe_path);

    data = {};
    povrate.forEach(function(d) {
      data[d.GEO] = d['2013'];
    });


    console.info(data);
    svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(land.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke","#000")
      .style("stroke-width",".5px")
      .style("fill",function(d){
            var value = data[d.id];
            if (isNaN(value)){
              value = data[d.id.substring(0,2)];
            }
            if (isNaN(value)){
              return "#fff";
            }

            return scale(value);
            })
      .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
            var value = data[d.id];
            if (isNaN(value)){
              value = data[d.id.substring(0,2)];
            }
            div.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 0.9);
            div.html("<b>"+d.properties.name+"</b><br/>" + value + "%")
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
      .on("mouseout", function(d,i) {
          div.transition()
              .duration(500)
              .style("opacity", 0);
        });

        svg
          .append("path")
            .style("fill","none")
            .style("stroke","#000")
            .attr("d", projection.getCompositionBorders());


  });




  })
}

dropdown.on("change", change)
change(); //trigger json on load



</script>






</body>

<!-- // d3.json("nuts2.json", function(error, europe) {

// }); -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining europe_path as a string "europe.object.nuts1" rather than the object europe.object.nuts1. Remove the quotations and try it.

edit start ****

If the goal is to allow a user to toggle between two layers, you can dynamically load a topojson with a variable name such as in:

[Toggle Topojson with file reload](http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/18c99da4ea475797738b6c7e62fb1639)

Which takes an approach similar to the presented code.

But, if the goal is to allow toggling between two or more layers, it might be easier to load them once, and toggle visibility, as in:

[Toggle Topojson with visibility change](http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/0cc5dfb9eedba7afd6712303fb983533)

This will generally be smoother and quicker as the paths do not need to be recalculated from reloaded topojson files.

edit end ****

Comment: but I need to read that in as a string you know? sometimes it's `nuts`, sometimes it's `nuts2', so I want to pass it as a variable

Comment: I was too quick to answer, didn't see it through. Thought about it right after I hit enter

Comment: I just put the code- maybe it will give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do

Comment: it's basically that I want people to be able to switch between two map views

Comment: :/ what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127499/discussion-between-s-matthew-english-and-andrew-reid).